# Cannot get Asia/Kolkata WindowsMap in NodaTime

Tags: .net-core, timezone, nodatime

Put simply, I have a dot net web app and it needs to record the users Timezone information (in order to send out the correct time inside emails).

```
using NodaTime.TimeZones;
var winmap = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.MapZones
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TzdbIds.Contains(tzinfo));
if (winmap == null) throw new Exception("Invalid timezone");
```

NodaTime 2.4.8

https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_WindowsMapping

The "Asia/Kolkata" timezone doesn't seem to exist, and I'm not sure what is needed to make it work. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just for clarification - is this Noda Time? It looks like it... in which case I'd suggest adding the right tag. If it is, I suspect it's the version of Noda Time that's important here. It shouldn't be anything to do with the system time zone database.

Comment: Updated, yes Nodatime.

Comment: Right. I *suspect* this is a problem where you're actually using different versions of Noda Time (and therefore different data) on the different platforms. Please log `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.VersionId` both locally and on Azure, and update the question. (Also log `tzinfo` to check that you're really checking for the same thing in both cases - we don't know where that value comes from.) Once that's in place, I suspect I'll be able to answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help @JonSkeet. I assume the version deployed is going to be the same as the version I am using locally, since I am building the project locally and simply deploying it to azure - how could it be different? (Not using any middlemen bots, CI stuff yet)

The reason for this issue is because I saw in the log an exception when the user tried to update their timezone to this. I have a unit test that runs this function with `Asia/Kolkata` which succeeds locally. It works with all other timezones (that my users have signed up wtih so far).

Comment: I just double checked my testing and something is off, I'll get back soon thanks

Comment: I updated the question. My unit test was giving me a false positive locally (trash test), after I fixed it, correctly it fails locally too, so it's nothing to do with Azure.

I see 'Asia/Kolkata' in the list on https://nodatime.org/TimeZones  but I'm just not savvy with NodaTime here, what is it I need to update....

Comment: The problem is that Asia/Kolkata isn't in the Windows mapping file - but Asia/Calcutta is. If you can update to NodaTime 3.0, you can use `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.TzdbToWindowsIds` - see https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_TzdbToWindowsIds for details.

Comment: Will add an answer along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Windows/TZDB mapping file ([example](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/blob/master/data/cldr/windowsZones-37.xml)) doesn't contain "Asia/Kolkata", it contains "Asia/Calcutta".

Accounting for this in user code is relatively tricky, which is why in NodaTime 3.0 we introduced [`TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.TzdbToWindowsIds`](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_TzdbToWindowsIds).

After updating to 3.0, you can use:

```cs
if (!TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.TzdbToWindowsIds.TryGetValue(tzinfo, out var windowsZoneId))
{
   throw new Exception($"Unmapped time zone ID '{tzinfo}'");
}
// Use windowsZoneId here
```

If you *really* need to stick with 2.4.8, you could canonicalize both `tzinfo` and all the entries in `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.WindowsMapping.MapZones.TzdbIds`, but that will be generally worse.

(The update from 2.4.8 to 3.0.0 should be seamless for most users. It's a breaking change *primarily* due to removing binary serialization, which I hope you're not using...)